# Problems parsing a xml file

Tags: python

I am editing a xml file that is originally like that:

```
    <SequencerLoopCommand id="1073" 
     IterationCount="2"
     CommandList="1241 1242"
     Name="Loop Stream IDU64ToIDU63">
      <IterateLoadSizeCommand id="1241" 
       LoadType="STEP"
       LoadUnits="KILOBITS_PER_SECOND"
       LoadStart="100"
       LoadEnd="200"
       LoadStep="100"
       CustomLoadList=""
       StreamBlockList="1543"
       Name="Iterate Stream IDU64ToIDU63">
      </IterateLoadSizeCommand>
      <WaitCommand id="1242" 
       WaitTime="5"
       Name="Stream IDU64ToIDU63">
      </WaitCommand>
    </SequencerLoopCommand>
```

With the following code...

```
doc = minidom.parse("directory")

#processing

fh = open(os.path.join(self.__dirname,self.__xmlfile),"w")
doc.writexml(fh)
fh.close()
doc.unlink()
```

after that, my new xml is something like:

```
<SequencerLoopCommand CommandList="1241 1242" IterationCount="2" Name="Loop Stream IDU64ToIDU63" id="1073">
  <IterateLoadSizeCommand CustomLoadList="" LoadEnd="200" LoadStart="100" LoadStep="100" LoadType="STEP" LoadUnits="KILOBITS_PER_SECOND" Name="Iterate Stream IDU64ToIDU63" StreamBlockList="1543" id="1241">
  </IterateLoadSizeCommand>
  <WaitCommand Name="Stream IDU64ToIDU63" WaitTime="5" id="1242">
  </WaitCommand>
</SequencerLoopCommand>
```

I need that the new file to have the same structure as the old one. Any tip?

Thank you

Comment: The way I know `xml.dom.minidom` it leaves whitespace alone unless you explicitly change it. What do you do in the `#processing` bit of your code? Do you normalize somewhere along the way?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not easy by default as both XMLs are identical (from parser POV).

However, You can write custom SAX serializer that will break & ident attributes. See http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.handler.html#module-xml.sax.handler , but I'd say it's not worth the effort.